# I'm worried my neighbour drinks alcohol while driving, should I confront him?

Tags: neighbors

I live in a condo and park next to my neighbour in the lot. On multiple occasions as I've gotten out of my car, I've noticed an open can of beer or cider in the the front cupholder of his vehicle. Open containers of alcohol anywhere in a vehicle is illegal where we live (Ontario), as I understand it. I can't prove that he's drinking and driving, or even drives with it as an open container (he's also a smoker, maybe he uses an empty one as an ashtray?).

We're casual acquaintances on good terms with each other, and I'll chat with him for a while if I'm outside while he's having a smoke (which isn't that often). Is this something I should try confronting him about? I feel like if he is doing something as socially unacceptable as drinking while driving, he's not going to care what I have to say (plus, I could come off as nosey for looking in his car. It's not something I've been doing on purpose). At the same time, I feel like I need to do *something* since he's potentially putting other's lives at risk. Is this even any of my business?

What can I do? Should I do anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about what someone should or shouldn't do are about a personal decision not an interpersonal skill.

Comment: Welcome to IPS. You're asking about "what to do" and "should I" and unfortunately those kind of questions are off topic here. It would be on topic if you already decided what to do and were asking about how to better interact with your neighbor.